# Querying the Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

[image: Neo4j problem]

Hi guys!

I'm getting this error while I'm doing certain queries to test Neo4j, but I don't understand this error. Could someone explain to me this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: For Google the error was "Expected a parameter named 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use {1} and {2} for query parameters while not using parameters (which you can not do in the browser)

so remove the {} from your query :

```
MATCH (person1:Person {id:1}), (person2:Person {id:2})
...
```

Comment: FYI if you end up making queries from a programming language make sure to always use parameters when you have dynamic data going into your query.  It's more performant and more secure: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip @BrianUnderwood